# CRM Advanced Find all the icons in wrong place

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I've just loaded up the advanced find and I cant click on half the icons/drop downs as they are all in the wrong place. It works fine on other servers and other machines. It appears as if its a CSS problem. Any Ideas

[image]

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several users reported this issue, the cause is not clear yet, however these are the suggested steps:

1) Try with another browser

2) Clean the browser cache

3) if CRM site is inside the Internet Explorer compatibility mode list remove it

4) if CRM site is not inside the Internet Explorer compatibility mode list add it

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in Firefox. (In private mode, there was no problems.)

**Steps to fix it:**

1. Goto/Open the CRM Site
2. Open Developer Tools
3. Go to Console Tab
4. Enter the following command:

   `localStorage.clear(); // remove all of localStorage's properties`

Comment: This worked for me after trying the steps in the post from Guido

Comment: Same, this also worked for me in IE11 Windows 10 after also previously trying to empty the cache.

Answer (score 3):

```
localStorage.clear();
```

This did the job for me on Chrome

Answer (score 1):

For Edge, a less severe fix is:

- From the CRM app tab or window,  F12 for Debugging tools
- Select the Application tool from the tool bar,
- Expand Local Storage on the left,
- Below that select the line that has the URL for your CRM
- Right-click, select Clear.
- Restart Edge.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Edge settings
- Click the Reset Settings button
- Restart session

[image: Edge Reset Settings]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Internet Options
2. Go to Security Tab
3. Click On Trusted Sites then Sites and Add CRM Site to Trusted items
4. Recommended to click on Custom Level and disable Pop-Up Blocker

Now Problem is solved