# CRM 2013, Advance find page is broken, CSS out of order after SQL timeout exception

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have been trying to resolve a very simple issue i had yesterday. But i am still unable to make this right.

i was working CRM advanced find to filter out some records, when suddenly an SQL time-out exception occured (that because one of our other team member was importing a solution).

Now the advance find view look like this  [image]

All the buttons are out of style.

I tried following:

1. `clearing cache of IE`
2. `reset browser settings`
3. `Ctrl +F5`
4. `Ctrl+Shift+r`
5. `Deleted temporary internet files`

Nothing will make it right.

**P.S:**  This works find in google chrome for me and in IE for all other team members except me. :(

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807495/crm-advanced-find-all-the-icons-in-wrong-place

Comment: @GuidoPreite i tried the steps mentioned in the answer but it not working for me.

Comment: then the problem is with your Internet Explorer installation

Comment: i had the same problem in firefox. This works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807495/crm-advanced-find-all-the-icons-in-wrong-place/33119790#33119790

Comment: @s.dewald Thank you so much this worked for me, :)